# Why is a Manager().dict() only updated one level deep?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I wanted to update a `dict` in a `dict`, the outside one being instantiated via `multiprocessing.Manager()`:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(key, container):
    # this one is not applied
    container['a'][key] = key
    # this one is
    container[key] = 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    c = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
    c['a'] = {}

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('x',c,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('y',c,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print(c.copy())
```

The output of this code is

```
{'y': 3, 'a': {}, 'x': 3}
```

I expected to get

```
{'y': 3, 'a': {'x': 'x', 'y': 'y'}, 'x': 3}
```

**The first level of the `dict` is addressable in `worker`, but operations on the nested `dict` are silently discarded. Why?**

I initially thought that this my be due to the shallow copy, but the output is the same when using `copy.deepcopy()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Manager` is implemented using a subprocess that keep a local version of your `dict` object and provide proxy functions that mimic the behavior of the object without `Manager`.
When you call `container['a']`, you use the proxy function that return a local copy of the value associated to the `'a'` key. Thus if you modify this copy in one of your subprocess, the change is only local. If you want a global change, you can either:

- Modify the local copy and synchronize by using the proxy of `set`, *ie* `container['a'] = new_dict` as you proposed. The inconvenient is that it is not atomic and thus you have some concurrency issues as if `p1` and `p2` gets the dictionary, both get `{}`, and the update they submit will be `{key: key}` only, without taking into account the other update and only the second one will be registered in the end.
- A better way would be to use a nested `Manager.dict`:

  ```
  import multiprocessing


  def worker(key, container):
      container['a'][key] = key
      container[key] = 3


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      multiprocessing.freeze_support()

      manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
      container = manager.dict()
      container['a'] = manager.dict()

      p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('x', container))
      p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('y', container))

      p1.start()
      p2.start()
      p1.join()
      p2.join()
      print(container.copy())
      print(container['a'].copy())
  ```

Comment: Also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73418403/16310741) to automatically create managed objects incase an attempt to store a nested dictionary/list is made. This makes it so that you can freely update the `container[a][key]` without creating a nested managed dictionary yourself.

Comment: when used in nested function this is not working

Answer (score 2):

I think this is [a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6766).

I found an esoteric way to bypass the issue, I am not sure how robust it is. Any feedback is welcome.

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(key, container):
    add = {key: key}
    container['a'] = dict(container['a'], **add)
    container[key] = 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    c = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
    c['a'] = {}

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('x',c,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('y',c,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print(c.copy())
```

This outputs

```
{'y': 3, 'a': {'y': 'y', 'x': 'x'}, 'x': 3}
```

Comment: I am using this trick to update the dict from a child process. If you started with:
`c = {'y': 3, 'a': {'y': 'y', 'x': 'x'}, 'x': 3}`
you could do this:
`c['a'] = {**c['a'], **{'y': 1234}, **{'b': 'xxx'} }`
and end up with:
`{'y': 3, 'a': {'y': 1234, 'x': 'x', b 'xxx'}, 'x': 3}`

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the instance of the Manager to subprocesses, for example

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(key, container, manager):
    container[key] = manager.dict()  # create a dict using current manager
    container[key][1] = 3
    container[key][2] = manager.dict() # # create a dict using current manager
    container[key][2]['hh'] = 'test'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as m:
        c = m.dict()
        c['a'] = 1
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('x',c,m))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('y',c,m))

        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        print(c['a'])
        print(c['x'][1])
        print(c['x'][2]['hh'])
        print(c['y'][1])
        print(c['y'][2]['hh'])
```

The output is

```
> $ python3.7 ddd.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1
3
test
3
test
```

Comment: this just throw brand new error for me 'AttributeError: type object 'SyncManager' has no attribute 'from_address'' and its unquitable without ctrl \

Comment: Which version of Python did you use? Can you show the whole error traces?