# Shared Object not being updated when using multi-processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get some rows from multiple dataframes and store them in a custom object using multi-processing.

***Code***

Here's the code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


class DataOperationMultiProcess:
    @staticmethod
    def get_row_single(new_symbol_df_shared, symbol_df, s, index, columns_dict, columns):
        df = symbol_df.symbols[s]
        df_columns = df[columns]
        new_symbol_df_shared.value.symbols[s] = df_columns.iloc[index]
        print(new_symbol_df_shared.value)

    @staticmethod
    def get_row_multi(symbol_df, symbol_data_frame_class_name, index, symbols, columns):

        new_symbol_df = symbol_data_frame_class_name()
        columns_dict = symbol_df.column_names()
        manager = mp.Manager()

        new_symbol_df_shared = manager.Value(type(new_symbol_df), new_symbol_df)
        pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
        for s in symbols:
            pool.apply_async(DataOperationMultiProcess.get_row_single,
                             args=(new_symbol_df_shared, symbol_df, s, index, columns_dict, columns))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        return new_symbol_df_shared.value
```

the `symbol_data_frame_class_name` is just a custom object that is similar to a dictionary.

****Problem****

in `get_row_single` function when i try to print the value of `new_symbol_df_shared` it returns an empty object. and at the end when printing the value of `get_row_multi`it's still an empty object.

What is causing this and how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `multiprocessing` docs say: "If standard (non-proxy) list or dict objects are contained in a referent, modifications to those mutable values will not be propagated through the manager because the proxy has no way of knowing when the values contained within are modified." This also applies to objects similar to list or dict. Try to finally reassign in worker process like `new_symbol_df_shared.value = new_symbol_df_shared.value`.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be relevant here https://stackoverflow.com/q/73409151/16310741